# Why do they laugh when Rose Maxon says these words?

Tags: plot-explanation, fences

In one scene of Fences, They all laugh in this scene when Rose Maxon says these words:

[image]

> Man, hush your mouth. You ain't say no such thing. Talkin' about,
>   "Baby, you know you'll always be number one with me."

What is so funny in these words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I remember Troy was explaining how he conquered Rose. I don't remember the exact words they used in the scene, but was something in these lines:

Troy explaining what Rose and him said in the night they met:

> Rose: What will be number one for you, baiseball or me?
>
> Troy: You know it will baiseball, but if you work on it, you can get close.

Then Rose said the phrase you mention on your question, basically telling it was a lie, that Troy was crawling for her:

> Baby, you know you'll always be number one with me.